# Using JQXGrid with JQueryUI tabs widget

Tags: jquery-ui-tabs, jqxgrid

Hope someone can help.

I'm having a bit of problem loading a JQWidgets Grid (JqxGrid) into a JQueryUI tabs widget. Whenever I set the grid width to a percentage value, it seems to change it to a pixel value. So for example, a width of 100% gets converted to 100px. Now I know there was a similar problem with previous versions of JqxGrid and the JqxTab components and that has been resolved, but unfortunately I'm not in a position to change my tab widget at this point. If anyone knows how to work around this issue, your help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Here's my code:

```
$("#studentgrid").jqxGrid({
        width: '100%',
        source: studentAdapter, 
        theme: theme,     
        filterable: true,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        autoheight: true,
        altrows: true,
        enabletooltips: true,
        autoshowfiltericon: true,
        groupable: true,
        columns: [
            {text: 'Programme / Unit', datafield: 'student_unit', width: '30%'},
            {text: "Involvement Type", datafield: 'student_type', width: '30%' },                
            {text: 'Student Count', datafield: 'student_count', width: '20%' },
            {text: 'Student Level', datafield: 'student_level', width: '20%' }
        ]
    });
```

Comment: please post the code for your grid init....are you placing the 100% inside single quotes? => width: '100%'..........you can also try using  => width: 'auto'......and I've experienced unexpected behavior by using percents for width and height due to the order in which the elements are created....

Comment: Hi. I've added my code block. I've tried using single quotes, double quotes, putting the width declaration in front as well as the end. No difference. This behavior only occurs in the UI tabs widget. If I create the grid outside the tabs, it works as expected. Also, if I use grouping then the group header doesn't display correctly either.  As soon as I rebind the grid, it display as expected.

Comment: Is it possible that your Grid is being created in the DOM before the tabs are completely initialized?

Answer (score 0):

Uhm...After a day of struggling, I solved it. I think it's a a glitch with JqxGrid because it's turning the percentage values to pixel values, so 85% becomes 85px and 100% becomes 100px. (then again, it's possible I'm doing something wrong as well).
Anyway, turns out that if you hide content tabs BEFORE initializing the grid, the percentage values get converted to pixel values. So for example, I had the following code above the grid initialization

```
$("#tabContainer").tabs();  
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content
    //On Click Event
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content

        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content                     
        return false;
    });
```

and the grid behaved strangely, but as soon as I moved it below the grid initialization, everything worked as expected again.

Answer (score 0):

jqxGrid does not turn percentage into pixels or at least it does not in its latest version - http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/autosize.htm

Comment: The latest version does seem to change the percentage to pixels but only when used inside a tab widget and only when the tab containing the grid is hidden before the grid is initialized. Test it and see.